# django and ajax without jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I am trying to submit a form using ajax to django view but without jquery, and i am not able to get through few things.

1. I am unable to send formData to django via ajax
2. Also unable to check if the request is made via ajax or not (request.is_ajax())

I am using core Javascript for this functionality so any help will be appreciated.

Views.py

```
def register(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        if request.is_ajax():
            # form is submited via ajax
        else:
            # error submitting the form via ajax
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error':'There was an error'})
else:
    form = RegisterForm()
context = {
    'form' : form
}
return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

AJAX

```
function _(e){
    return document.getElementById(e);
};

function getCookie(name){
    var cookieValue = null;

    if(document.cookie){
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++){
            cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            if(cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')){
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length+1));
                break;
            };
        };
    };
    return cookieValue;
};

var btn = _('formBtn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fname = _('id_first_name').value;
    var lname = _('id_last_name').value;
    var email = _('id_email').value;
    var password = _('id_password').value;
    var csrfCookie = getCookie('csrftoken');

    // formData not working

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    };

    ajax.open('POST', '/users/registerAjax/', true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrfCookie);
    ajax.send(encodeURI('first_name='+fname+'&last_name='+lname+'&email='+email+'&password='+password));

})
```

Comment: If `btn` is a button, you should `event.preventDefault()` on the form not the button. I would just make your form submit via an `<input type='submit' />`, then just make it `formElement.addEventListener('submit', function(eventObj){ /* code here */ eventObj.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: actually its <input type="submit" id="formBtn" value="Register">